# How to account for credit card fees in reports?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, payment, accounting, financial-accounts

How can I account for credit card processing fees in reports?  For example, if a member renews via credit card for $15, we only get $14.26 after the processor takes their cut. I'd like to be able to generate reports that will match up with our accounting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Contribution details report](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/8?reset=1&output=criteria&force=1) and include 'Fee amount' as column and filter as Payment Method In Credit Card.

Also you could use [BookKeeping report](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/20?reset=1&output=criteria&force=1), with filters as

1. Financial Account Name - Debit In Banking Fees
2. Payment Method In Credit Card

[image]